# Regular expression freezes

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
pattern = re.compile("([a-z]+-*[a-z]+)+$")
```

But when I run:

```
pattern.match("departamento-de-archipielago-de-san-andres-providencia-y-santa-catalina")
```

The line doesn't finish, that is, the program freezes.

I have tried with:

```
pattern.match("departamento-de-archipielago-de-san-andres-providencia-y-")
```

and it doesn't work

finally, I have tried with:

```
pattern.match("departamento-de-archipielago-de-san-andres-providencia-y")
```

And that does work!
I don't understand what is wrong here. Is it a bug?

I'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: No, it isn't a bug, it's a *catastrophic backtracking* caused by your pattern design.

Comment: You have a pathological regex. Look that up. You probably want `[a-z]+(-+[a-z]+)*$`.

Comment: Click on *regex debugger* to see what happens: https://regex101.com/r/SbeoHB/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
re.compile("([a-z]+-[a-z]+)+$")
```

will work better for what it looks like you are trying to do. The regex you provided is called [pathological](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), because `-*` causes it to run away with an absurd amount of possibilities.

If you really want multiple hyphens, `-+` is fine too.

Comment: Note that it's always a bad design because the second `[a-z]+` generates a lot of backtracking steps at each group repetition. Look at Ryan pattern design that is from far more efficient.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte agreed